# Bitcoin Cash Sent to Vaultoro

Tags: transactions

I accidentally sent Bitcoin Cash from my Coinbase wallet to my wallet at Vaultoro. The problem is it didn't show up because Vaultoro only takes Bitcoin.

Can anyone give me a step by step on how to retrieve this? I tried to get Vaultoro to help but they didn't seem to care.

Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic, as you'll need to contact Vaultoro in order to have your funds returned, making this a customer service query.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to recover your coins is to get Vaultoro to do it as they own the private key. Some other services charge a recovery fee for this, others don't even offer a way to recover such funds.